# How do I vote to close?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, privileges

A few days ago, I was notified that I had earned the privilege to view and vote to close Questions - and as I came across a bad question today (It was even worse than this question) I wanted to give it a close-vote, but I couldn't figure out how.

The guide on the website looks like this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

But when I look at questions, this is all I see:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Am I doing something wrong here? Is the button located somewhere - painfully obvious to everyone else?

Comment: You've earned the privilege to [view close votes _on your own questions_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes). You'll need [a bit more rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) to view and cast close votes on others' questions. Until then, use your flags when you feel a question should be closed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes

Comment: Yeah yeh!!! I didn't delete the comment in time. I saw just as I posted my stupidity :D

Comment: Don't worry about it, the privilege page is a tad confusing, it doesn't really emphasize that the privilege only applies to your own questions.

Comment: This was before I discovered meta, but I know when I passed the 250 mark, I kept looking for questions that had close votes so I could view them.  It took me a while to figure out that it was my own questions I could view the votes on.